# replacing prepositional phrases

Tags: word-order

A sentence in a book,

> It will be evident that poet’s function is not to report things that have happened, but rather to tell of such things as might happen , things that are possibilities by virtue of being in themselves inevitable or probable.

‘by virtue of being in themselves inevitable or probable’

Does the meaning change if the PP goes behind?

‘by virtue of being inevitable or probable in themselves’

Comment: Yes, it does change, in the original it is modifying the verb *being* while with the change it is modifying *probable*.

Comment: It's easy to imagine a situation where putting the PP at the end would raise the possibility that it modifies only the last preceding word. Putting it ahead of the compound predicate strongly suggests that it modifies (or at least applies to - I'm not sure what it technically modifies) both components. Context can make the choice less important, but as a style rule, context is best used to fill ellipses, not to fix bad word order.

Comment: In this case, it does not change the meaning. However, your paragraph needs some work.

Comment: I see three answers as comments. :^(

Comment: Something that is inevitable is always more than just a possibility—it's a certainty. So, the syntax of the sentence aside, the meaning is dubious in the first place, and asking about the order of the wording isn't going to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, with the clause headed by the participle **being**, there is no nearby subject noun phrase for **in itself** to qualify.  But when we do have such a noun phrase,  **in itself** (or "in themselves" as the case may be) is clearest after the subject noun phrase, and then after the BE verb, and then the farther away it gets the less clear things get.  They don't get ungrammatical, just less clear.

> It *in itself* is insufficient basis for a charge of conspiracy and must be coupled with other evidence of *mens rea*.
>
> It is *in itself* insufficient  basis for a charge of conspiracy and must be coupled with other evidence of *mens rea*.
>
> It is insufficient  basis *in itself* for a charge of conspiracy and  must be coupled with other evidence of *mens rea*.
>
> It is insufficient  basis  for a charge of conspiracy *in itself*  and  must be coupled with other evidence of *mens rea*.

Comment: Thanks! Then what would be a better way to rephrase my example? Does this one flow " things in themselves that are possibilities by virtue of being inevitable or probable."

Comment: I don't really see what *in themselves* adds to that sentence. In fact, **probable** refers to an outside context, and runs counter to the notion of *in itself*.